# Add and Edit in the same form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I need to create an application that will add and edit in the same form.  I implement this example http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/K3gJT/. I try to change the code to implement the add but I am stuck with this.

```
var Item = function(data) {
 this.name = ko.observable();
 this.price = ko.observable();

 //populate our model with the initial data
 if(data != null) {
    this.update(data);
 }
};

//can pass fresh data to this function at anytime to apply updates or revert to a prior    version
 Item.prototype.update = function(data) { 
  this.name(data.name || "new item");
  this.price(data.price || 0);
 };

 var ViewModel = function(items) {
  //turn the raw items into Item objects
    this.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function(data) {
    return new Item(data);
  }));

//hold the currently selected item
this.selectedItem = ko.observable();

//make edits to a copy
this.itemForEditing = ko.observable();
this.Add = ko.observable();
this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
this.acceptItem = this.acceptItem.bind(this);
this.revertItem = this.revertItem.bind(this);
};

ko.utils.extend(ViewModel.prototype, {
//select an item and make a copy of it for editing
selectItem: function(item) {
    this.selectedItem(item);
    this.itemForEditing(new Item(ko.toJS(item)));
},

acceptItem: function(item) {
    var selected = this.selectedItem(),
        edited = ko.toJS(this.itemForEditing()); //clean copy of edited

    //apply updates from the edited item to the selected item
    selected.update(edited);

    //clear selected item
    this.selectedItem(null);
    this.itemForEditing(null);
},

//just throw away the edited item and clear the selected observables
revertItem: function() {
    this.selectedItem(null);
    this.itemForEditing(null);
}
});

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel([
 { name: "Cheese", price: 2.50 },
 { name: "Pepperoni", price: 3.25 },
 { name: "Deluxe", price: 4.25 }
```

]));

Comment: I do not see where you are trying to add. All you should have to do is myObservableArrayName.push(item).

Comment: yes correct I just need to add .push(item) but what I want to add it in the same form where I do an editing.. if I add a method addItem I still need to pass the itemForEditing so that my form will be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a button for adding a new item

```
<button data-bind="click: addItem"> Add new item </button>
```

and connect it to this function in your viewmodel

```
var self = this;
self.addItem = addNewItem;
function addNewItem() {
   var newItem = new Item();
   newItem.name = 'new item';
   self.items.push(newItem);
}
```

edit: Added it to you fiddle, working with add

Comment: your example is awesome but what I need is when I click the Add new Item button the form will appear same form where he edit and he will add in the same form

Comment: you can call the click on the new Item after adding it to the list to open it in the edit form

Comment: In your example when I clicked add new item it will automatically add the item what if the user click the cancel it  will still add.. is there a possibility that when I click Add New Item it will only be push when I click accept..?

Comment: then you will need to add addition of the new item to be in the accept button (that means you need to know if it's new or not, and if it's new to push into the list)